# Return row field on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible in a SQL request to do such a thing:

In 1st table (Product), I have the folowing:

**id         name**
1               Table
2           Chair

In 2nd table (color), I have the folowing:
**id         productID             color**
 
1                     1                            red
2                      1                          green
3                      2                            white

I would like to get for each product a list that tell me in wich color is exist in my dbb.
For example, I would like that the SELECT returns 2 rows:
in the 1rst row: Table, red, green
in the second row: chair, white.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Every result from the result set of a query has the same number of fields.

You can fake it with GROUP_CONCAT, though:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.color)
FROM Product AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN color AS c ON p.id = c.ProductID
GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: Dont trust anymore on implicit sorting (ORDER BY) with GROUP BY this is been official deprecated as off version >= 5.6.. you should always use an explicit `GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY p.name` or if you dont want the sort overhead `GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY NULL`

Comment: Thx<br> That was exactly what I needed.
Just one more question please. How can I replace the ',' by a word like 'and'?

Comment: @IsraGab Didn't you find anything relevant in [the documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `JOIN` will provide the matches between the rows, and `GROUP_CONCAT` will help you produce a single line list:

```
SELECT   name, GROUP_CONCAT(color) AS colors
FROM     product
JOIN     color ON product.id = color.product_id
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Dont trust anymore on implicit sorting (ORDER BY) with GROUP BY this is been official deprecated as off version >= 5.6.. you should always use an explicit `GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY p.name` or if you dont want the sort overhead `GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY NULL`